# How to use recursion to find a logical dual

Tags: function-construction, recursion, logic

I want to make a little function that goes through a propositional formula and gives it's dual.

Here is what I currently have:

```
dualfunction[p_] :=
   If[p[[0]] === Not, Not[p], 
   If[p[[0]] === And, Or[Not[p[[1]]], Not[p[[2]]]], 
   If[p[[0]] === Or, And[Not[p[[1]]], Not[p[[2]]]], 
   If[p[[0]] === Symbol, Not[p], p]]]]
```

Now, it does give a dual for example a simple formula like `p && q`.

But without recursion, it cannot go through a formula `p && ( q || r)`.

I cannot get the recursion working.

Any ideas?

Comment: Isn't `LogicalExpand` enough? `p && q // Not // LogicalExpand`

Comment: No. In order to change the Head, there cannot be more than two propositional symbols at the same 'level'. Mathematica cannot tell the difference between p && (q && r) and p && q && r.

Comment: And where is this stated in your question? Moreover, from which perspective those parenthesis `p && (q && r)` matters?

Comment: It matters because to be able to change the head of expression you need to find the 0th head of the expression. In p && q that is &&. However in p && q && r mathematica can only recognize the first &&, not the second. Even the parenthesis do not help. Same applies to built in AND, XOR, OR and so on.

Comment: Sorry maybe someone else will help you, I still don't know why `p && ( q || r) // Not // LogicalExpand` is not enough. I'd put `dualFunction = LogicalExpand @* Not`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want recursion, write recursively.

```
dualF[Not[p_]] := Not[dualF[p]]
dualF[And[p_, q_]] := Not[Or[Not[dualF[p]], Not[dualF[q]]]]
dualF[Or[p_, q_]] := Not[And[Not[dualF[p]], Not[dualF[q]]]]
dualF[p_Symbol] := p
```

then

```
dualF[p && (q || r)]
```

> `! (! p || (! q && ! r))`

which has the truth table

[image: table1]

which is same as

[image: table2]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Very helpful. I am very new Mathematica user, so the language is new for me. Also I am not yet a programmer. Recursion is wonderful.